# saving, reading and securing data of apps directory in android

Tags: android, file, security, android-internal-storage

I am trying to save file into internal memory and also that should be readable by my application only.
till now I have tried this.

```
  String filesave  =     Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+""+getFilesDir()+"/.fkfk";
    File f = new File(filesave);
    if (!f.exists()){
        f.mkdir();
    }
File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    Log.e("files", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+f.getAbsolutePath());
String path  = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/.NEWFolders/hdfc0002.jpg";
    File toCopy = new File(path);
    if (toCopy.exists()){
        Log.e("ok","got the path");
        try{
            if (sd.canWrite()) {
                File source= toCopy;
                File destination=f;
                if (source.exists()) {
                    FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(source).getChannel();
                    FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(destination).getChannel();
                    if (dst != null && source != null) {
                        dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                    }
                    if (src != null) {
                        src.close();
                    }
                    if (dst != null) {
                        dst.close();
                    }
                }else {
                    FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(source).getChannel();
                    FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(destination).getChannel();
                    if (dst != null && source != null) {
                        dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                    }
                    if (src != null) {
                        src.close();
                    }
                    if (dst != null) {
                        dst.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

but this code snippet is throwing FileNotFound exception.
Please suggest  me on the same.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is mixed up:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+""+getFilesDir()+"/.fkfk";
```

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory` and the `getFiledDir()` method of Context refer to two completely different locations - the first on the primary "External Storage" (which these days is typically a permanent part of the device), and the second in the app's private storage area.

You should use only one of these methods to discover a location that best fits your goal.   You might consult [Storage Options](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) or [Saving Files](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html) in the Android documentation to aid your decision.  If you wish something to be used only by your app, you would typically want the Internal Storage - ie, getFilesDir().

Once you have chosen a location, you will need to make the rest of your code consistent with it.

Comment: I want to use private data directory for application can you please elaborate more on this

Comment: See the links to the android documentation provided.